# Implementing FilterTreeTable in Vaadin 6

Tags: filtering, implementation, vaadin, treetable

I started my project in Vaadin 7. Due to unavailability of Filter Treetable support from [FilteringTable](https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/filteringtable) add-on in Vaadin 7, I downgraded to Vaadin 6. I saw they have implemented FilterTreeTable in Vaadin 6 [here](http://tepi.virtuallypreinstalled.com/filteringtable?restartApplication). And they have provided how to use [code](https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/filteringtable). But, That code works fine for FilterTable. Where Can I get some demo code for implementing FilterTreeTable? If I get the demo code of the demo application, it will be very nice.

Comment: I'd really recommend at least planning to use Vaadin 7 in the end. There are a lot of important [new features](https://vaadin.com/blog/-/blogs/the-next-reindeer-is-here-vaadin-7-0-0-is-out). For some reason I can't load the link to the Vaadin 6 FilterTreeTable, but maybe given the Vaadin 7 one lists the issue " * Filtering does not work in PagedTable or TreeTable" You'd be better off waiting for that, or maybe trying to help fix / implement that in the add on yourself?

Comment: Yes you are right. But, I have waited enough for it already. And I have everything that I need for my work in Vaadin 6 itself. So, I took a hard decision to downgrade to Vaadin 6.

Comment: No probs. you continue your project in Vaadin 6. You can migrate it to Vaadin 7 easily. Read their documents. Check this https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Migrating+from+Vaadin+6+to+Vaadin+7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out Line no 195 in this [link](https://github.com/tepi/FilteringTable/blob/vaadin6/src/org/tepi/filtertable/demo/FiltertabledemoApplication.java). They have demo code that implements FilterTreeTable in vaadin. Don't forget to add DemoFilterGenerator and DemoFilterDecorator classes to your Project.

Comment: The one who previously answered this question also said the same. It's my mistake. I didn't understand what he tried to say. This one should go for him. he deleted his answer, and you got it fresher.

Comment: Ahaan.. He missed it and I get it.